# javaldx failed! Warning: failed to read path from javaldx (in docker containe using php)

Tags: php, symfony

When I was not using docker it was working after moving to docker I am getting this error. I am new to docker. Please help out here.

javaldx failed!
Warning: failed to read path from javaldx

(process:55): dconf-CRITICAL **: 15:28:49.193: unable to create directory '/var/www/.cache/dconf': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

Here is the code

```
$process = new Process(sprintf('%s --headless --convert-to pdf --outdir %s %s', $this->libreOffice, $toFolder, $filePath));
$process->run();

if (!$process->isSuccessful()) {
    throw new \Exception($process->getErrorOutput());
}
```

Comment: Can you share more details? That error message looks completely unrelated to PHP or Symfony to me

Comment: As I have already motioned that it was working earlier but now moved to docker server and it started giving that. here is an exception 

CRITICAL - Uncaught PHP Exception Exception: "javaldx failed! Warning: failed to read path from javaldx (process:101): dconf-CRITICAL **: 05:57:10.525: unable to create directory '/var/www/.cache/dconf': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Added the below command in the DockerFile and it started working.

```
RUN mkdir -p /var/www/.config /var/www/.cache && chown -R www-data. app/cache app/logs /var/www/.config /var/www/.cache
```